# Is the creature in Superman #11 a known figure?

Tags: dc, superman, the-new-52

Is the creature from another dimension that is encountered in Superman #11 known to us. Should we recognize him / it from previous works?

[image: Superman battles an unknown alien]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, I am well-versed in the lore of Superman, and this being is unlike any seen before in the previous DCU Superman's rogue's gallery. It clearly appears to be alien, and bears more than a passing resemblance to the Predator, equipped with a range of powers and technology allowing him to challenge Superman.

The technology is sufficiently changed but note the helmet, the hanging braid-like extensions at the head and feet. This creature also has a reptilian tail, not seen on the Predators.

Comment: When I saw the creature I originally thought it WAS a predator, until I saw the tail.

Comment: To me it bears a passing resemblance to Equus from the "For Tomorrow" storyline

Comment: Equus was a human supersoldier developed by the OMAC protocols in a fashion similar to the Weapon X programs in the Marvel Universe. He was enhanced with cybernetic weapons capable of harming Superman. You can zoom a look here: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/b/b3/Superman206.jpg

Comment: @JackBNimble https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman_versus_Predator